# Getting ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch in PostsController#create in Rails App

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, devise, ruby-on-rails-4.2

```
Started POST "/posts" for ::1 at 2016-01-16 20:55:15 -0800 
Processing by PostsController#create as HTMLParameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"RZREVs4Wy7ZWvo4u0xE5OmrawV2MYtxJNJZDfs+eQY8o2n1RthJsL5c1MklIpP+XlMGNbDYSD49fjna7Szq/1g==", "post"=>{"start"=>"2", "end"=>"1", "when(1i)"=>"2016", "when(2i)"=>"1", "when(3i)"=>"17", "when(4i)"=>"06", "when(5i)"=>"00"}}
User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 5ms (ActiveRecord: 0.2ms)
ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch (Location(#70172044981120) expected, got String(#70171989781540)):app/controllers/posts_controller.rb:8:in `create'
```

Full Trace activerecord(4.2.4)lib/active_record/associations/association.rb:218:in`raise_on_type_mismatch!'
    activerecord (4.2.4) lib/active_record/associations/belongs_to_association.rb:12:in 'replace'
activerecord (4.2.4) lib/active_record/associations/singular_association.rb:17:in`writer'
activerecord (4.2.4) lib/active_record/associations/builder/association.rb:123:in `start='
activerecord (4.2.4) lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:54:in`public_send'
activerecord (4.2.4) lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:54:in `_assign_attribute'
activerecord (4.2.4) lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:41:in`block in assign_attributes'
actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_controller/metal/strong_parameters.rb:185:in `each_pair'
actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_controller/metal/strong_parameters.rb:185:in`each_pair'
activerecord (4.2.4) lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:35:in `assign_attributes'
activerecord (4.2.4) lib/active_record/core.rb:564:in`init_attributes'
activerecord (4.2.4) lib/active_record/core.rb:281:in `initialize'
activerecord (4.2.4) lib/active_record/inheritance.rb:61:in`new'
activerecord (4.2.4) lib/active_record/inheritance.rb:61:in `new'
activerecord (4.2.4) lib/active_record/persistence.rb:33:in`create'
app/controllers/posts_controller.rb:8:in `create'

post.rb

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :start, :class_name => 'Location'
  belongs_to :end, :class_name => 'Location'

  validates :start, presence: true
  validates :end, presence: true
  validates :when, presence: true
  validates :user_id, presence: true
end
```

PostsController.rb

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!
  def new
    @page_title = 'Add Post'
    @post = Post.new
  end
  def create
    @post = Post.create(post_params)
    # save the post
    if @post.save
        flash[:notice] = "Post Created"
        redirect_to posts_path
    else
        render 'new'
    end
  end
```

...

```
private
  def post_params
        params.require(:post).permit(:start, :end, :when, :description, :seats, :round_trip).merge(user_id: current_user.id)
  end
```

new.html.erb

```
<h2>Add New Post</h2>
<% if @post.errors.any? %>
    <% @post.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <div class="alert alert-danger"><%= msg %> </div>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
<%= form_for @post do |f| %>
    <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.select :start_location, Location.all.collect {|x [x.city_name, x.id]}, {:include_blank => 'Select One'} %>
    </div>
   <div class="form-group">
            <%= f.select :end_location, Location.all.collect {|x| [x.city_name, x.id]}, {:include_blank => 'Select One'} %>
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
       <%= f.label :When %><br />
       <%= f.datetime_select :when, :ampm => true, :minute_step => 15 %>
   </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    <%=link_to "Cancel", root_path, class:'btn btn-default' %>
<% end %>
```

schema.rb

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20160117041612) do
  create_table "locations", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "city_name"
    t.string   "state_name"
    t.string   "zip"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end
    create_table "posts", force: :cascade do |t|
      t.integer  "start"
      t.integer  "end"
      t.datetime "when"
      t.text     "description"
      t.integer  "seats"
      t.integer  "user_id"
      t.integer  "round_trip"
      t.datetime "created_at",  null: false
      t.datetime "updated_at",  null: false
    end

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "first_name",             default: "", null: false
    t.string   "last_name",              default: "", null: false
    t.integer  "location_id"
    t.string   "email",                  default: "", null: false
    t.string   "encrypted_password",     default: "", null: false
    t.string   "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer  "sign_in_count",          default: 0,  null: false
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.string   "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.string   "last_sign_in_ip"
    t.datetime "created_at",                          null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                          null: false
  end

  add_index "users", ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true
  add_index "users", ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true

end
```

I literally have no idea why I am getting this problem. A post has a start and end location. It also has a user_id, where the user has signed in through devise. Please help.

Comment: 'end' is a reserved keyword in ruby: have you tried renaming `:end` to something else (e.g. `:end_location`)?

Comment: Unfortunately, that did not work.

Comment: Can you add your view code as well? I assume start, end, and when are all Date or DateTime?

Comment: I have added my view code. start_location, end_location, and when (of type DateTime) are all set in the view code or at least they should be.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't working because you're passing strings to attributes that accept a Location class instance.  Since start and end are shown as being class Location in your model, your form either has nested attributes using fields_for, or you have selects to choose a location.  If you have nested attributes you need to add

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :start, :end
```

to your Post model and then update post_params to have the correct parameters

```
def post_params
  params.require(:post).permit(:when, :description, :seats, :round_trip, start_attributes: [<fields in start>], end_attributes: [<fields in end>).merge(user_id: current_user.id)
end
```

if instead you have selects for choosing the locations, then you need to make sure they are returning start_id and end_id as the params and update your post_params to

```
def post_params
  params.require(:post).permit(:start_id, :end_id, :when, :description, :seats, :round_trip).merge(user_id: current_user.id)
end
```

Update:
  Now that you've posted your form we can see you have selects.  Your schema also shows that you have start and end in the posts model as integers.  Normally those should be start_id and end_id or you will need to use the :foreign_key option with belongs to.  Also, your two selects currently are passing parameters as start_location and end_location, which aren't valid parameters for any of your models.  If you fix the naming of start_id/end_id then you would update the selects like

```
<%= f.select :start_id, Location.all.collect {|x [x.city_name, x.id]}, {:include_blank => 'Select One'} %>
```

and update your post_params to permit start_id and end_id. If instead you use the :foreign_key option, then it would be

```
<%= f.select :start, Location.all.collect {|x [x.city_name, x.id]}, {:include_blank => 'Select One'} %>
```